# PostgreSQL SELECT when integer unique - invalid input syntax

Tags: sql, postgresql, tkinter

```
  cur.execute("""SELECT  name, number 
    FROM store
    WHERE number=%s OR name =%s""",
    (number, name))
```

My problem is that number is INTEGER UNIQUE and when I try to select by number everything is ok, but if I try to select by name I received an error:

> invalid input syntax for integer

Comment: You need single quotes around a string literal.

Comment: You should be using parameters, rather than munging the string!

Comment: @unutbu it does not work for me

Comment: Also note that the [`invalid input syntax for integer` error may occur](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18298348/190597) if an empty string is passed as an argument instead of an integer. If that is the problem, `int(number)` will raise a ValueError on the Python side.

Comment: @glaadys: We want to help you but "it doesn't work" is never informative enough. Instead, please tell us what error message you see.

Comment: It is my problem actually, because in GUI tkinter I would like to have an option to search my database only by providing the name OR number, not providing both

Comment: On the Python side I entry a string, my database has a column with int unique number, and text name. When I am inserting data, everything works but the problem is when I try to select from database (through GUI tkinter) item which has entered name without providing number

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `number` is sometimes not an integer, such as an empty string.
You could handle this on the Python side by assigning `number` to `None` whenever `int(number)` is invalid:

```
try:
    number = int(number)
except ValueError:
    number = None

cur.execute("""SELECT  name, number 
    FROM store
    WHERE number=%s OR name =%s""",
    (number, name))
```

`cur.execute` will handle `None` as `NULL`.

---

> in GUI tkinter I would like to have an option to search my database only 
>   by providing the name OR number, not providing both

If you want to search by `number` (first) or by `name` (second), but never both,
then use

```
import psycopg2
try:
    cur.execute("""SELECT  name, number 
        FROM store
        WHERE number=%s""", (number, ))

except psycopg2.DataError:
    cur.execute("""SELECT  name, number 
        FROM store
        WHERE name=%s""", (name, ))
```